# Replacing Pandas column data inline

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have a pandas dataframe with a "gender" column in which every value is "m" or "f".

I want to make a seaborn barplot where the labels are "Male" and "Female".

I could do this ...

```
df['gender'] = df['gender'].replace({"m":"Male", "f":"Female"})
sns.barplot(data=df, x="something", y="value", hue="gender")
```

... but that's not ideal if I only want to change the "gender" column temporarily just for plotting.

Is there a way to change the values in one column inline?

... something like this:

```
sns.barplot(
    data=df.replace({"m":"Male", "f":"Female"}, col="gender"), 
    x="something", 
    y="value", 
    hue="gender")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `assign` to create a new data frame without modifying the original one:

```
sns.barplot(
    data=df.assign(gender=df.gender.replace({"m":"Male", "f":"Female"}), 
    x="something", 
    y="value", 
    hue="gender")
```